# Should I use vh or vw as responsive units?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a little confused regarding which units are the best for responsive websites.
I know the pixel units are static and it's better to work with `vh` or `vw` to get better responsive results.

Which one is better to work with a responsive design?

Comment: See [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for current browser support of `vh` (and all other HTML/CCS/browsery goodness stuph)

Answer (score 3):

I would use 'rem' everywhere. Additionally set the root font size (on the html) dynamic with javascript or relative to the screen size with vw or vh.

Comment: Downvoting is no problem, but please tell me why! So I can learn from it.